# Better way to copy only the updated data from Oracle to Solr

Tags: sql, database, oracle, solr, architecture

We have an Oracle Database which has about 500 000 records and we have an etl job which runs every day and it will delete all the records from Oracle and reinsert the data (because some of the data is updated on every day) and in this process the lastupdatedTime for all the records is current day. This whole process is maintained by some other team.

And We have an application which is related to search, for this we are using Solr for the better performance. To use Solr, we are reading all the data from Oracle DB and storing into SolrCollection and this is a separate Job.

My questions, is there any better way to get only the modified records from Oracle and update only those into my Solr Collection. If we go with lastUpdatedTime in Oracle Db it wont help in my scenario.

Comment: Can you clarify the first paragraph again please? As I understand it the process deletes all the records and then reinserts them? Why? Also can you explain exactly why you cannot use lastUpdatedTime?

Comment: Are you willing and able to perform changes to your database? I have one or two options in my mind, but you will at least require one additional table, to keep track of your records.

Comment: Could you change the update process to use MERGE or something to keep the timestamps intact? If your DB doesn't know what has been updated (i.e. you'll have to track what has been updated in some way, either directly in the table or with a secondary table as cheffe mentions), Solr won't have a chance either

Comment: @the4thamigo_uk There is a Admin team which updates the data on every day into there database which is maintained by some other team and we don't have  any control on it.  We have a ETL job which reads the data from there database and storing into oracle database which drops and reinsert all the data on everyday. Because of this the lastUpdatedTime is showing current day for all the records.

Comment: @Cheffe, Admin team updates few records  on every day into there database  and we don't have any control on it. The ETL job which reads the data from there database and storing into our Oracle which drops and reinsert all the data on everyday. Because of this the lastUpdatedTime is showing current day . There is a one more job which is reading the data from Oracle and  inserting into Solr. No idea what are the records that are updated  with the ETL  job and  we are reading all the data from Oracle and and inserting into Solr Collection. How can we do this using secondary table?

Comment: @MatsLindh, please check my above comments and if there is a way to track with the secondary table that is useful for me. please provide your suggestions.

Comment: After the table has been updated, select all rows that has changed (i.e. join on id, then have a where-statement that compares the values you want to watch for a change) - you could do this through an UPDATE .. JOIN .., and update the timestamp for those rows that changed. Then have Solr select based on that timestamp. (I'm not familiar with exact syntax for Oracle's SQL, so you might have to move it into a procedure)

Comment: Oracle, OK. Did you get an access user (schema) to connect to the database? As your work is spread to that extend I would assume yes. If not, ask for it. Once you have your own schema and got the grants to access the data schema, you may create your tracking table in your own schema.